# Max formula ignoring text

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to display the next ID number using the max formula for a column that contains an ID number with both text and number (e.g., XXX0043). Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: better provide a list of sample ID number so we know what kind of combinations you may have in the list, and what is the expected outcome for each sample ID.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your IDs are in A1:A10, and the numeric part is always the last 4 characters:

```
=MAX(--right(A1:A10,4))
```

use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when confirming the formula instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when { } show up around your formula.  Note that the { } cannot be added manually.

[image: POC]

UPDATE:  Based on Solar Mikes comment

```
="xxx"&RIGHT("0000"&MAX(--right(A1:A10,4)),4)
```

With the assumption that xxx does not change...if xxx changes then it a little more complicated.

Comment: If you want the original ID to be displayed then same instructions , but like this: ="xxx"&MAX(--RIGHT(A1:A3,4))  Plus 1 anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike see update.  Need to add those leading zeros back in before concatenation.  Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: Could use left() to get the 3 characters in a spare cell somewhere and reference that, but still good, shows how much can be done... You sorted the hard bit ...